# Identify HTML tags within rows of Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with rows like this:

```
Column A:

<span style="font-family">This is a test</span>
<li>Hello there</li>
<xi> Hi </xi>
```

I want to loop through each row in the dataframe and check for occurrence of words beginning with < and ending with >.

How do I do that?

I know I could loop through the dataframe like:

```
For r in zip(df['Column A']):
```

But how could I spot out the words in the row that begins with > and ends with <
? I want to spot them because I want to remove the HTML tags.

Comment: could there be a random text along with html tags within a column value?

Comment: Nope...everything within tags is essential

Comment: I meant: may a column contain `some non text <li>Hello there</li> with expression 1 > 0`  in distinct row?

Comment: nope. It will always start with a HTML tag and end with a HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
import re
def html_occurences(in_str) : 
    # Match all occurences of text between <>
    matches = re.findall(r'<(.*?)>', in_str)
    # Then you can count occurences in matches for each html element
    return matches
# Matches will be a pandas.Series of matches that you can cast as a list for instance
matches = df['A'].apply(html_occurences)
```

Comment: since you're using the lambda function to shuttle off the arg to your `html_occurrences` func, you could just directly call `apply(html_occurences)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the route of [parsing html with regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2487336) (which is *usually* ill-advised), you could use the help of an html parser module like [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/index.html).

```
from lxml import etree

def extract_elem(html):
    root = etree.fromstring(html)
    return root.tag

res = df['html'].apply(extract_elem)

print([x for x in res])
# outputs: ['span', 'li', 'xi']
```

The advantage here is that if any of your rows have nested html, you can expand the `extract_elem` func to descend into the html structure.